# Why does Email to Salesforce think my emails are spam?

Tags: email

Email's which we are sending to Salesforce in order to associate with records in Salesforce  is not getting associated with any records .In fact ,when I send an email to salesforce using outlook then salesforce is classifying it as spam and in the subject it puts

{SPAM: 40} :Undeliverable: and sends it back to us and the rest of the error is given below.

This message was created automatically by the mail system.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

> > > emailtosalesforce@dmsi81qidzeggr6vknn7rr7oosgsgdyccyvb1ttzshtw64lg6.
> > >       8-dea8eae.c.le.salesforce.com (Undelivered): 551 Failed due to: 
> > >       SenderAuthorization.

I do not understand how salesforce can classify it as spam.I have tried sending it from three different email addresses using outlook but it always sends it back as {spam 40}

and when I try to send it through Yahoomail it works perfectly fine.It works fine in Production as well as sandbox.We do have valid email addresses registered in the section email to salesforce so that is not the problem

What can we do to resolve this issue? or what do u guys suggests.I hope some salesforce technical employee can guide us.

Comment: taking a wild hit here : Are you having any IP restrictions for your Org? setup --> security controls --> network access check if there is a IP range from which the emails are accepted and if the IP from which you are trying to send is not available in the list. Also can you screenshot and paste your email handler setup.

Comment: ?? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14164/email-to-salesforce-error did you try what was suggested to you in this thread

Comment: If you haven't already you really should contact Salesforce support.  You might get lucky, but chances are this is going to require knowledge of Salesforce's internal setup that no one on this forum has or would be able to share.

Answer (score 1):

You should contact salesforce for a more detailed answer, but this looks like the [Sender Policy Framework (SPF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) records for your domain are set up to tell recipients to block email unless it comes from your mailserver(s).

Typically these records only allow email to be sent from a specific IP address, and if your outlook is sending through a different mailserver it would be blocked by the SPF records your DNS admin has configured.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation .When I try to use same outlook from the office and send a message to the email address associated with the contact in my personal org, message does get attached in the active history related list.However,When I send a message as an email to the company org from the same outlook ,it gets refused as spam and it does not work. Can u please send me the link on the above explanation which u have provided.I am not sure I have been able to understand your explanation completely.But thanks for the help.If what u are saying is true then Is there a solution to this problem

Comment: Hi Ca_peterson.  MyCompany outlook ---company server----salesforce -------salsforce server .Now here mycompany is the culprit or salesforce server is the curprit and who has to make changes.Yes,this is SPF issue as I have put some keywords in Google such as helo from the detailed error message and it took me to SPF.Now who has to make configuration changes,my company or Salesforce.Does that mean salesforce expects messages to come from one particular IP and microsoft outlook is sending it using different IP ,therfore,emails are returned by salesforce server as spam.Is that correct?Please advic

Comment: Your company would have to make the changes. Specifically whoever administers your mailserver and DNS system.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000Sz4xAAC) with a Release In Progress. The link documents a workaround.

> ***Some customers experiencing issue sending emails using Email-To-Salesforce due to PRVS implementation***
>
> **Summary**
>
> Some customers may have a email security mechanism implemented on their outgoing mail servers called "Bounce Address Tag Validation" (BATV). The mechanism determines whether the bounce address specified in an email messaged is valid.
>
> Essentially, this method prepends following in envelope-from field of
>   the email header:
>
> (XXXXXXXXXX = numeric unique identifier)
>
> Now due to a recent change on Salesforce side, our application servers
>   are currently rejecting emails where the envelope-from in the email
>   header has an email in the above format if an email is sent to E2S
>   email address.
>
> **Repro**
>
> If a customer (on NA8) sends an email to their E2S email address
>   or using Salesforce for Outlook Add Email button they may get a bounce
>   back message with content similar to below:
>
> *emailtosalesforce@a-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.c.le.salesforce.com (Undelivered): 551 Failed due to: SenderAuthorization*
>
> **Workaround**
>
> Currently, the workaround is to add your email address in
>   PRVS format under Email-To-Salesforce, My Acceptable Emails setting:
>
> Setup | Personal Setup | Email | My Email to Salesforce
>
> **For example:**
>
> Actual email:  jdoe@acme.com
>
> PRVS email:  prvs=XXXXXXXXXX=jdoe@acme.com
>
> **Note**: The PRVS format can be retrieved from your email headers
>   envelope-from or you can consult your internal IT to get the correct
>   PRVS format email.