# Inbound Email Service: Failed due to: SenderAuthorization

Tags: apex-email-service, inboundservices

I'm developing an inbound email service to parse the email and create records in a custom object. This service was working fine in my developer org, but when I deployed this to a full sandbox for testing, Salesforce bounces the email saying

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

feedback_listener@2juegqq3k5646u6aqv1lktcyha3s5lw3mm8tlf24spj0aajef2.g-30owseaq.cs17.apex.sandbox.salesforce.com (Undelivered): **551 Failed due to: SenderAuthorization**

Initially, the 'Accept Email From' was blank (for testing purposes), but it still didn't work. I added our domain names and then added the specific tester's email address, still didn't work. Interestingly, it did work when I sent the email from my email address.

I came across this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14164/email-to-salesforce-error),

*Now due to a recent change on Salesforce side, our application servers are currently rejecting emails where the envelope-from in the email header has an email in the above format if an email is sent to **E2S** email address.*

but I guess this scenario applies only for "Email to Salesforce".

Here is the screenshot of my configuration.

[image]

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is resolved.

Apparently, it looks like there is a setting to restrict the email address / domain in one another place from other than the 'Accept email from' setting while defining the email service and this setting is located in the 'Email Service Address' page.

[image: Email Service Address]

This setting had my email address populated (which meant 'accept emails only from my email address') and once I removed this, the problem was resolved. When I created the new email service address, it automatically populated my email address which I didn't notice in staging, but probably removed it in my developer org, which is why it worked in my developer org.